# solution for a differential equation with non linear term

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=S\left(t\right)^{y}-\gamma K\left(t\right)$$

If I had a linear specification like $aS(t)$ instead of $S\left(t\right)^{y}$, I would multiply both sides by $e^{-at}$ but since I have a concave function, I don't have a clue to solve this differential equation for $S(t)$. $\gamma$ and $y$ are constant parameters.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\frac{d \dot S}{dt}$?  I guess it means $\frac{d^2S}{dt^2}$, though I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I edited.

Comment: Is there, perhaps, another typo and the last term  on the left is multiplied by $S(t)$? Because that will be a Bernoulli type equation, which is easy. If the last term is $-\gamma K(t)$, then I have no idea.

Comment: This is a special case of the [Chini Equation](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor/Chini) (A generalization of the Riccati and Abel's equations), given by:
$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=f(t)(y(t))^n+g(t)y(t)+h(t)$$
There is no known general method to solve them, however some [specific cases](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ytnat-fracdyt/41181#41181) have a straightforward approach to solve them.